# AIR/Android - play video from mounted OBB/expansion file

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, video, air, apk-expansion-files

I have about 125MB worth of video files that I need to play from an expansion file (OBB). The OBB file itself is in place and is successfully 'mounted' using a [3rd party native extension](http://pol2095.free.fr/Air_APKExpansionFiles), so I can access the files using traditional methods, like the File class, the Loader class, etc.

I use the NetStream and NetConnection classes to play the video file, but the problem is that for the stream to play, the video file needs to be in the same folder as the SWF that is trying to play it (or a subfolder). This is also in the Adobe documentation:

> Play a local file
>
> In Flash Player and in AIR content outside the application security
>   sandbox, you can play local video files that are stored in the same
>   directory as the SWF file or in a subdirectory; however, you can't
>   navigate to a higher-level directory.

I tried to play the stream nevertheless, just out of curiosity, and it throws a StreamNotFound error (as it should, because the video file is not in the same folder/subfolder as the SWF). My hunch is that this is some security sandbox thing, and there's a way around it, but I can't find it.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: if it was a security sandbox issue it would tell you. My guess is that it can't discover the file. I don't know what you mean by 'mounted' but the obb file is just a zip file so it should simply be unpacked in the app security sandbox tree so its file are accessible. If you do anything else you are just looking for trouble.

Comment: As far as I know the OBB file is whatever I want it to be. So I used the 'jobb' command line tool in the Android SDK to create the OBB file. The ANE I use enables me to access the OBB without unpacking it, thus 'mounting' it for all intents and purposes. If I unpack it into any writable folder, the NetStream still wouldn't be able to play the file, because the video file still wouldn't be in the same folder as the SWF. I'll explore this, though. Thanks.

Comment: The problem with this approach is that the location of the OBB can change from device to device and there's no guaranty the user won't be able to delete it by simply doing a cleaning of some kind. That's why it's at least recommended to move that file to a secure location to start with and even better to unpack it to its correct place. Personally I look for my files in the app root and go find them in my OBB if they don't exist, then I copy them in my app root. User never has to wait for anything and after a while all my files are in the root.

Comment: Thanks, I see how that could work, but won't all the unpacking/copying increase the space used by the app? My app is around 300MB, so any unpacking would require the same amount of space. So for installation I'd need around 600MB. Plus removing and deleting the OBB file is explicitly not recommended by Google: http://developer.android.com/google/play/expansion-files.html#Rules Also by Google: 'However, if possible, it's best if you use an expansion file format that allows you to read directly from the file instead of requiring you to unpack the data'

Comment: @Nedudgi can you tell me how did you add the extension to adobe flash? I am new to adobe and want to test this out, thank you.

Comment: @mrahmat In the end I went with a paid solution by [Zooom](http://www.zooom.at/app-shop.html). The free ANE by Pol didn't work for me. The Zooom version has a very good getting started guide.

Comment: @Nedudgi thanks for the reply, I wish there was an easier way with the free ANE's because I am a student and doing this for learning purpose and would be pointless to pay for the ANE

Comment: @mrahmat The free Pol version that I tried somehow messed up event bubbling and caused a lot of trouble for me. If you're not trying to do anything serious you can give it a shot to test stuff, but I don't recommend it for production purposes.

Answer (score 0):

Eventually I was able to play a video file from the mounted obb using the built-in as3 VideoPlayer class, which it seems is able to play video from any folder.